# Do shulkers despawn in Peaceful Mode?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was raiding an End City for fun, and I was almost dead, so I switched the difficulty from hard to peaceful mode. The shulker that I was fighting immediately despawned, so I healed myself back up and switched the difficulty to hard. The shulker did not respawn. I tried this experiment again, but I got mixed results. Sometimes, the shulkers would despawn and respawn, despawn permanently, or stay put but remain passive. What is going on, and if there is a probability, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange, as Shulkers shouldn't despawn at all. Nor should they ever respawn.

According to the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shulker):

> **Spawning**
> Shulkers spawn during the generation of end cities, which are located on the outer islands of the End. They usually spawn on the walls of the city and on end ships. They do not despawn naturally, even in Peaceful difficulty, and once killed, they do not respawn unless spawners are used.

> In Peaceful difficulty, shulkers exist within the world, but do not attack, like vindicators and evokers.

Meaning it's especially confusing that you encountered both despawns and respawns.

I can only assume that the shulker that despawned initially actually teleported away:

> When at less than half health, a shulker has a 25% chance of teleporting (as described above) after taking damage. When a shulker is attacked, other shulkers in the area target the attacker as well.

But I have no idea how you managed to get multiple despawns during testing.

Comment: They definitely do not despawn in Java Edition. I suspect Bedrock is bugged in this respect.

Comment: Or perhaps the wiki is wrong. Wouldn't be the first time someone posted nonsense there and others take it for granted.

Comment: The shulkers **did not** teleport. I scoured the entire city for "new" shulkers (they teleported away), but there were none.

Comment: The wiki primarily has info about Java Edition, and sometimes doesn't tag paragraphs that are JE-specific.

Comment: This is certainly very unusual, and likely an oversight in BE's code. I might do a code dive later today on the Win10 version to take a look.